# Merge multiple GA unsampled report data into one dataset(view)

Tags: date, merge, google-analytics, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have been using Google Data Studio to build dashboards for Google Analytics 360 data. The data is currently being fetched through Google BigQuery in order to avoid sampling. 
However, BigQuery comes with a limitation that it could only fetch 13 months of previous data from the time it was implemented. So data beofre 13 months can't be pulled into BigQuery using SQL. I read it somewhere that I could generate the unsampled report for the date range before 13 months and then pull them together with SQL code in BigQuery to combine with current GA data.

I have exported 2 unsampled report CSV files from GA with 5 parameters and import those CSV as dataset in BigQuery,
I try to make scheduling query for appending data to “ExportTwo” dataset. that works for me for testing purpose.

But I am facing issue with parameter type miss match as in GA its consider date as INTEGER while importing CSV and when scheduling in big query to append sessions data in “Export Two” dataset, I can not append session data into that as its giving me error for type mismatch for date.

Also I need to check for all parameters name and type from GA and BigQuery should be same which we are using in all the reports

How can we merge multiple GA unsampled report data(5 columns) into one dataset(view)? As I can import one csv, I can’t have option to merge csv to any dataset as of now.

Answer (score 2):

According with the [CSV Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#limitations) when you load CSV or JSON data, values in DATE columns must use the dash (-) separator and the date must be in the following format: YYYY-MM-DD (year-month-day).

For your second inquiry, Did you try [appending to or overwriting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#appending_to_or_overwriting_a_table_with_csv_data) a table with CSV data?

If you load data into an existing table, the load job can append the data or overwrite the table.

I suggest to take a look in  the [CSV options](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#csv-options) to know all the available options to works with CSVs files in BigQuery.